# Have to design a lottery program that using Arrays and Arraylists that print results for the whole year

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I have to write a program that mimics Megabucks lottery game.
It should either let the user enter 6 numbers OR automatically pick 6 numbers and 1 bonus number. The troubling part is that I have to design it in a way that it will produce 104 drawings(2 drawings a week for 52 weeks). I can't seem to write the code in a way that the 104 drawings are all randomized.

Here's the code I have for drawing the 6 winning numbers and 1 bonus number:

```
import java.util.*;
public class oops
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int bonus = randomGenerator.nextInt(42)+1;
            List <Integer> winningNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
            for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                   winningNumbers.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(42)+1);
            }
            System.out.println(); 
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(" Winning numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(winningNumbers.toArray()) +" Bonus Number:" + "[" + bonus + "]");
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");


    }
}
```

And the output for that part is:

[image]

As for my code for the rest of the program:

```
public void getPlayNum()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter 1 for manual picking or 2 for automatic:   ");
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    List <Integer> playNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(input == 1) //let user pick out their own play numbers
    {
       for(int i =0; i< 6; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number 1 and 42 (no duplicates): ");
            int userNum = scan.nextInt();
            if(playNumbers.contains(userNum))
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** DUPLICATE FOUND! Please enter a non-repeating digit between 1 and 42 ***");
                i--;
                System.out.println();

            }else if (userNum > 42 || userNum < 1)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("*** OUT OF RANGE! Please enter a non-repeating digit between 1 and 42 ***");
                i--;
                System.out.println();
            }else{
             playNumbers.add(userNum);

             System.out.println("Here are your numbers: ");
             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(playNumbers.toArray()));
            }
        }
    }else{
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int index = 0; index < 6; index++)
        {
            playNumbers.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(42));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here are the numbers randomly generated for you: ");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(playNumbers.toArray()));
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Nothing is properly formatted but I need to fix the important parts first. Thanks for any tips at all!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I need to generate the winnings numbers 104 times and they must all be randomly generated and printed.

Comment: Why can't you loop it 104 times?

Comment: I don't know how...

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as @Gendarme mentioned:

```
for(int draw = 0; draw < 104; draw++) {
    int bonus = randomGenerator.nextInt(42)+1;
    List <Integer> winningNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
            winningNumbers.add(randomGenerator.nextInt(42)+1);
    }
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Winning numbers: "+ Arrays.toString(winningNumbers.toArray()) +" Bonus Number:" + "[" + bonus + "]");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```